# Best algorithm for batched insertion into & deletion from sorted vector?

Tags: algorithm

What is the best algorithm for batched insertion into & deletion from a sorted vector (i.e. growable array)? Assume that there could be multiple deletions and insertions all batched together, but not in general paired (i.e. sometimes more deletions, sometimes more insertions).

What is the time and space complexity? What is the real-world performance accounting for cache misses, etc.?

Does the best algorithm change if the data type reaches a certain size? In other words is the algorithm good for both 4-byte integers and for 40-byte structs?

Comment: What other operations do you need executed on this array? I expect all or subset of the operations defined by vector / array.

Comment: Iteration through the sorted elements, primarily.

Comment: Since I expect to be iterating through it many times a second, I'm thinking I could somehow pair the iteration with sorting of the alterations to the array from the previous iteration, thus reducing cache misses associated with the sorting. Single-pass partial bubble sorts on each iteration would eventually sort the array, but having only a partial sort might be overall worse due to the increased cost of finding a particular element when it is needed.

Comment: If insertions dominate the deletions you can consider using some sort of a heao - say Fibonacci or Binomial. Both are good in merging sorted sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!